# ExpressionEngine 1.6.8 Contact Form or just upgrade?

Tags: module, email, forms, upgrade, updating

I originally posted this on stackoverflow before discovering this specific forum...

I've been asked to make some changes to a site that was built with Expression Engine 1.6.8. Even though I'm not familiar with this CMS, I can find my way around to make the updates, except I'm not sure about adding a contact form. I'm guessing that ultimately I'll have to upgrade this version to the newest (2.7, I believe?) in order to get the tags found on this page to work: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/email/contact_form.html?

My only hesitation in making the upgrade is my unfamiliarity with EE, and the fact that someone else is probably creating a brand new website for the one I'm working on, and very likely without EE (so I'm learning something that I may not need again).  Are there any major issues that I'll run into making this jump from 1.6.8 to 2.7?  I wish the previous person maintaining the site had kept up with the upgrades.

Any suggestions for a quick fix, or should I just bite the bullet, upgrade, and use what I've found? **HOWEVER, I've now realized that I'm probably running core, in which the email module isn't even offered, so I'm sure my options are really limited...

Answer (score 2):

The EE1 docs are still available for [download](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/). Just look in the top right corner for a link to download the zipped docs. You can look for the section about the email module, which should do exactly as you need.

In this case, it may be easiest to just work with what you have. Upgrading to 2.7 from 1.6.8 could be quite an undertaking. Sometimes it works out really easily, but other times it can be pretty awful to deal with, it really depends on how the site is built and what add-ons are in play.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing my own html code within the template and processed it with a php script to send the form input to an email address, just as I normally would on a website.  Not being familiar with ExpressionEngine, I don't think I understood why I was continually being referenced to use a module in order to do this, but I suppose for anyone who is not a coder but is experienced with EE, that would be the way to go.  From what I understand, the email module is not free and does not come with the core version, which is what I had to work with, but comes with the licensed version, which made this all the more confusing.

Comment: I often use non-EE php scripts for contact forms -- it's often a better approach, imho. On the other hand, there are certain advantages for using native EE or EE add-on solutions to things. I like FreeForm, for example. But, if you don't need the solution to be inside of EE, and have a good and easy way to handle something outside of EE, I think that's totally a fair way to go.